# Problem on reflections - clarification needed

Tags: geometry

Suppose that $R_1,...,R_p$, $S_1, . . . , S_q$ are all reflections across planes that
contain $\bf0$. Show that if $R_1 · · · R_p = S_1 · · · S_q$ (denoting composition of reflections) then $(−1)^p = (−1)^q$ .

Now what I'm unsure about is that earlier in the book I'm given the following result:

Let $R$ be the reflection in a plane $\Pi$ that contains the origin.Then for all vectors $\bf x$, $\bf y$ and $\bf z$ (the expression in brackets is the vector product),

$$[R({\bf x}),R({\bf y}),R({\bf z})]=-[\bf x,y,z]$$

Now it would suffice to use it to prove the problem. But I suppose it is not so easy, is it?

Could somebody explain, what is the difference between the reflection across the plane and the reflection in the plane, and what is needed to tweak the latter result so that I could use it?

Thanks!

Comment: “vector product” of three elements? Looks more like a determinant to me. In any case, you can use the sign of a determinant to express cyclic order. Any single reflection will reverse that sign, so two equivalent compositions of reflections have to have equal parity.